# .kv file can't be run

Tags: python, kivy

i'm a beginner and i'm following tutorial kivy from youtube channel tech with team and i found a problem i.e. my .kv file can't start
this is my code
(main.py)

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
pass


class MyApp(App): # <- Main Class
def build(self):
    return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
MyApp().run()
```

(my.kv)

```
# Filename: my.kv

   MyGrid:

   <MyGrid>:
   GridLayout:
    cols:1
    size: root.width, root.height

    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        Label:
            text: "Name: "

        TextInput:
            multinline:False

        Label:
            text: "Email: "

        TextInput:
            multiline:False

    Button:
        text:"Submit"
        on_press: app.btn()
```

[so you can see that no button for run(i'm even tried with f5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmYWK.png)

please can you help me

Comment: You have to start the main.py file, not the kv one

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take care of your indented block. I don't know... maybe when pasting it here, the code text was messed up. I just fixed the indent block in main.py and my.kv, and then ran the code without a problem.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App): # <- Main Class
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
# Filename: my.kv

MyGrid:

<MyGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        Label:
            text: "Name: "

        TextInput:
            multinline:False

        Label:
            text: "Email: "

        TextInput:
            multiline:False

    Button:
        text:"Submit"
        on_press: app.btn()
```